# Search for all files whose parent is a specific folder

Tags: finder, search

I'm trying to create a smart search which will match the top-level contents of all folders with a specific name. E.g., imagine I apply this search to "foo" in the following folder structure:

```
/foo/x
/foo/y
/bar/foo/z
/bar/foo/z/a
/bar/foo/b
```

I would expect to get

```
x
y
z
b
```

I naively tried searching for "foo/*", but MacOS search doesn't support wildcards. Any ideas?

Comment: "top-level contents of all folders" folder z is in folder foo.  I believe you should be saying "top-level files of all folders.

Comment: See https://www.macworld.com/article/2926631/how-to-run-advanced-spotlight-searches-in-the-finder.html  See document container and raw select under other.  I would write it up, but I haven't got the "zen" yet.